# JavaScript (JQuery) validate numbers (decimals) in different cultures and DropDownListFor onchange

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have web app for testing.

My very simple class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

I changed my default controller this way:

```
// GET: MyClasses/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass()
    {
        Name = "First",
        Value = 1
    };

    var Names = new[]{
        new SelectListItem{ Value="First",  Text="First" },
        new SelectListItem{ Value="Second", Text="Second" },
        new SelectListItem{ Value="Third",  Text="Third" },
        };

    ViewBag.Names = new SelectList(Names, "Value", "Text");
    return View(myClass);
}

// POST: MyClasses/Create
// To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
// more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Value")] MyClass myClass, string Action)
{
    if (Action == "Change name")
    {
        myClass.Value = myClass.Name == "First" ? 1 :
                myClass.Name == "Second" ? 2 :
                myClass.Name == "Third" ? 3 :
                0;
        ModelState.Clear();
    }
    else
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.MyClasses.Add(myClass);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    var Names = new[]{
        new SelectListItem{ Value="First",  Text="First" },
        new SelectListItem{ Value="Second", Text="Second" },
        new SelectListItem{ Value="Third",  Text="Third" },
        };

    ViewBag.Names = new SelectList(Names, "Value", "Text");
    return View(myClass);
}
```

I changed "Create" view this way:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "MainForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>MyClass</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Name, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)new SelectList(ViewBag.Names, "Value", "Text", Model.Name), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "changeName()" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Value, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Value, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Value, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script>
        function changeName() {
            var input = $("<input>")
                .attr("type", "hidden")
                .attr("name", "Action").val("Change name");
            $('#MainForm').append($(input));
            $('#MainForm').submit();
        }
    </script>
}
```

I want make this app multilingual (change culture). I added some code to Global.asax.cs for it:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("someculture");
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("someculture");
}
```

This app works well when I use "en" or other culture/language ("someculture" in Global.asax.cs), DropDownListFor changes the Value, controller (async Task Create) works as it should.

My browser default culture/language is English. So when I use "fr" or other culture/language I get an error in "Create" view "The field Value must be a number.".
To fix this error user can change "," to "." in "Value", but it is not the solution.

To number validation I added the scripts I use in my other apps. I added its to "Create" view scripts section:

```
$.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) ||
        !isNaN(Globalize.parseFloat(value));
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    Globalize.culture('@(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name)');
});

jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.methods, {
    range: function (value, element, param) {
        var val = Globalize.parseFloat(value);
        return this.optional(element) || (val >= param[0] && val <= param[1]);
    }
});
```

But after adding this scripts DropDownListFor stopped working. Number validation is works, DropDownListFor - no.

My question is some way to do to work validation and DropDownListFor one time in one View? Or my approach is wrong and I should implement this functionality otherwise.

**UPDATE**

I found solution.

Added new input in view:

```
<input type="hidden" value="no" id="submitform" />
```

And modified scripts this way:

```
<script>
        function changeName() {
            var input = $("<input>")
                .attr("type", "hidden")
                .attr("name", "Action").val("Change name");
            $('#MainForm').append($(input));
            document.getElementById("submitform").value = "yes";
            $('#MainForm').submit();
        }

        jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.methods, {
            range: function (value, element, param) {
                var val = Globalize.parseFloat(value);
                return this.optional(element) || (val >= param[0] && val <= param[1]);
            }
        });

        $.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
            if (document.getElementById("submitform").value == "yes") {
                document.getElementById("submitform").value = "no";
                document.getElementById("MainForm").submit();
            }
            return this.optional(element) || !isNaN(Globalize.parseFloat(value));
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            Globalize.culture('@(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name)');
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: hey, just check for erros in your javascript console, maybe you have a problem related with the sequence you are putting your scripts, like you must put this after the jQuery script tag and so on...

Comment: Tried to change scripts sequence, put its to separate sections (<script>). No result. Will try use console, never used it before (I'm back-end developer, not front-end).